# Шкала времени с событиями Android

Tags: android

Пишу тестовое задание - планировщик дел с календарем. По заданию запланированные дела должны отображаться на шкале времени. То есть слева указано время по часам, а справа запланированные на это время события. Если ничего не запланировано, то соответственно пусто.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, какие средства использовать для отображения?
Буду рада любому совету

Comment: Посмотрите [эту библиотеку](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/970)

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать firebase от google например. Верстаете макет где будет время и событие. На отдельном слое добавляете recyclerView. Создаете адаптер и читаете из БД все что нужно. Примеров создания планировщиков дел в интернете достаточно много.